# How to use Decode Function in the case where column has string values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, decode

I have a view xxabc_v (shown below), I need to update the "Code" column to Null wherever it is N/A when "Value" column sum (900+(-900)=0) becomes zero for the "field_name" values (Demand A+Demand B) for the "Date" 01-Apr-21.

How can I put the decode logic to code column in the above case?

Table structure and expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `decode()` because a much simpler method works:

```
select nullif(code, 'N/A')
```

This returns `NULL` when `code` takes on the specified value.

If you actually want to *change* the data, then you want `update`:

```
update t
    set code = NULL
    where code = 'N/A';
```

EDIT:

I see, you have an extra condition.  So, use `case`:

```
(case when code = 'N/A' and
           sum(value) over (partition by id, date) = 0
      then NULL
      else code
 end)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply,I dont want to update the data as this is the view ,I want to modify the script query to  take the value as Null if the field_name values(Demand A+Demand B  ) =0 whenever their sum is zero.please refer the attached imaged in the question to know the view structure.

Comment: Thanks Gordon foe the help,latest solution posted is worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you need date wise id wise sum when to sum(). Please check this out:

```
select date,id,(case when sum(value)over(partition by date,id)=0 and code='N/A' then NULL
else Code end)code, field_name,value
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks Kazi for the help , solution worked fine.